# QGIS: When applying Multipart-to-Singleparts on MultipolygonZ creates duplicated geometries

Tags: qgis

I have a a file with geometries of buildings which I transformed from geo-XML to geopackage to facilitate working with it. The geometry type in the geopackage is now of type MultipolygonZ. However, if I now apply Multipart-to-Singleparts on the Multipolygons,  it creates for the geoemtry objects (multiple) duplicate(s).So the file was originally 3.9 GB, and after applyig Multipart-to-Singleparts the resulting file has 6.5 GB.
Can someone explain, what causes the duplicates (and probably how to prevend it)?

By duplicates I really mean duplicate geometries, so e.g. where a building is represented with one geometry before applying multipart-to-singlepart, it is aftwards represented by two geoemtries.

EDIT: It seems, that the geoemtries are duplicated according to the count of floors of a builing. So when a house has 3 floors, after applying multipart-to-singleparts, there are not one but three geometries.

Comment: What do you mean by "duplicates"? If you have multipart geometries, converting them into single parts will of course result in more geometries (one for each part) than before. So do you really get duplicate geometries - or just features with the same attributes, but different geometries? If the former, try `Delete duplicate geometries`, see https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#qgisdeleteduplicategeometries Otherwise, provide more information, maybe a sample dataset for testing and a screenshot.

Comment: Hi @Babel , I adjusted my question. It really are duplicated geometries. And I tried just before the 'delete duplicate geometries', but it was hanging at 91% processing and I stopped it. I will now first try to flatten the multipolygonZ with the saga-tool 'Flatten Polygon Layer'.

Comment: how did you apply multi to single? did you create a new table or add the output to the old one?

Comment: @IanTurton I'm not quite sure if I understand you correctly, but when I apply Multipart-to-Singleparts I created a temporary file, so a layer, which I then exported as geopackage. Is this the answer to your question? So I have two geopackages, each holds a single layer.

Comment: Could you provide some small dataset for testing?

Comment: Is it possible that in some or all of the multipart features there were already duplicated or partially duplicated features so when you converted them to single part the duplicates were now separated from each other?

Comment: @i.i.k. you should really provide a sample dataset, as already required twice. Otherwise, its difficult to understand what is going on.

Comment: @Babel You are right, but I just am not allowed to share the data (so I simply can't if I don't want to get into trouble ;). But I seem to have figured out what happened: The tool Multipart-To-Singlepart seems to create for each floor of the building a geometry. I will share my solution for this later, when I have figured out how to work this out.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the Multipart-to-Singlepart not only separates geometry objects based on their 2-D location, but also based on the z-variable. At least in my dataset it created for each building the amount of geometries equal to the amount of floors in that building.
The dataset I use is a cityGML-Dataset which is transformed to a geopackage.

There are several options for flating the data and dropping duplicates, e.g. use a combination of the tools in QGIS 'Flatten Polygon Layer', 'Delete Duplicate Geometries' etc
However, my data was to big for it (Data Size: ~ 4GB). So I had to break down my data into smaller pieces and iterate over the datafiles. For this I used geopandas.

0. Import relevant libraries and import your data

```
from shapely import wkb
import geopandas as gpd

MultipolygonZ_file = gpd.load_file('path/To/your/datafile.gpkg')
```

1. Create singleparts of your geopandas dataframe:

```
MultipolygonZ_file_single = MultipolygonZ_file.explode(index_parts=True)
```

2. Delete the duplicates based on the object id

```
withoutDuplicates = MultipolygonZ_file_single.drop_duplicates(subset=['object_id'], keep='first')
```

3. Remove the z-coordinate

```
_drop_z = lambda geom: wkb.loads(wkb.dumps(geom, output_dimension=2))
withoutDuplicates.geometry = withoutDuplicates.geometry.transform(_drop_z)
```

For the last step, you may like to read more about it here : https://gist.github.com/rmania/8c88377a5c902dfbc134795a7af538d8

This will create 2D-Polygons without duplicates.